# @things.each or 5.times do |t|

Tags: ruby, iteration

Is there a way to have an iterator that iterates anyways even when the object is nil?

For example, I'd like to strip my views from my application and create a dummy app for a designer.

So I would like it to iterate or loop.

How can this be done?

I've just found a way of doing it

```
<%
   (@messages.count == 0 ? Array.new(5).map { Message.new } : @messages.each).each do |m|         
%>
```

Comment: if you are not going to modify your messages, `Array.new(5, Message.new)` will work faster, besides `@messages.each` => `@messages`, you don't need to create enumerator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
(@things || dummy_things).each do |thing|
  # do something with thing
end

def dummy_things
  dummies = []
  5.times do
    dummies.push(Thing.new)
  end
  dummies
end
```

So what this does is to iterarte over dummy things if `@things` was `nil`, otherwise only iterate over `@things`.

#### EDIT

A more concise version of `dummy_things`, as mentioned by Victor, would be something like this:

```
def dummy_things
  (0..4).map{ Thing.new }
end
```

Comment: I feel that `(0..4).map{ Thing.new }` is much better than doing it manually

Comment: I agree. `(0..4).map{ Thing.new }` looks better.

Answer (score 4):

Answer is in your question only, even if you don't have any object, you can iterate 5 times using

```
5.times do |i|
  puts "Dummy page"
end
```